# Django migration emitting strange error message

Tags: django, django-queryset, database-migration, django-migrations

While writing a Django migration the following error message came up:

```
ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "MyModel": Use a QuerySet for "MyModel".
```

while doing a filter

```
mymodel_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(.....)
OtherModel.objects.filter(mymodel__in=mymodel_queryset)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you mix migration models and regular models while migrating like so:

```
from myapp.models import OtherModel
MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
```

Only use

```
MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
OtherModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'OtherModel')
```